# Clear CheckBoxList in one line

Tags: c#, performance, checkboxlist

Does anyone know how to clear a `CheckBoxList` in one line?

I have a `CheckBoxList` that holds hundreds of values and I'm just trying to speed up the code.

i.e. without iterating through each checkbox like so:

```
foreach (ListItem li in cblCategories.Items)
        { li.Selected = false; }
```

I know this isn't going to make a huge difference to the user experience - I'm just curious if anyone knows a more efficient way of doing this?
I was hoping for something like:

```
cblCategories.Items.Selected = none;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`ClearSelection` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.clearselection.aspx), which it inherits from the `ListControl` class.